# What happens with "$0" when you pipe data to bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, pipe

Say we have bash file like so:

```
cd $(dirname "$0");
```

instead of executing the file directly, what happens when we read the file and then pipe it through bash? How does the "$0" get interpreted?

```
echo "$(cat <file>)" | bash
```

The reason I ask is because it seems unclear what the $0 would mean since the file is no longer necessarily running where it once was located. Perhaps somehow bash remembers where it was located and the $0 still refers to the original file location? Seems highly unlikely.

Comment: Aside: `cd $(dirname "$0")` should be `cd "$(dirname "$0")"`.  But you shouldn't need to do either.  If you want to point to other files in the path, try something like `mydir="$(dirname "$0")"` and then check for existence of `"$mydir"/file-i-need`.

Comment: well...not really, if there are 4 commands in your shell script that need $0 as their pwd/cwd, then it's just most convenient to cd "$(dirname "$0")"...right? I find it to be a good way to enforce the expected/correct cwd for commands in the script.

Comment: I guess the quotes are important around "$(dirname "$0")" in case there is whitespace in the filepath, is that correct?

Comment: how does one downvote such a beautiful question lol

Comment: Man pages are not always clear, but on this particular topic, I find the description of `$0` quite clear.

Comment: The man pages for bash do not sound short LOL, combing for this information is not ideal. Now the next person can do a google search and hopefully find the information faster than reading the bash man pages, right? E.g.: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$0` would then be the name by which bash was invoked:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'echo $0' | bash
bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'echo $0' | ARGV0=sh bash
sh
$ printf '%s\n' 'echo $0' | ARGV0='blah blah' bash
blah blah
```

The second and third commands were run in zsh, which lets you set the 0th argument using the special variable `ARGV0`. But you can simulate that by using symbolic links:

```
$ ln -s "$(command -v bash)" foo
$ printf '%s\n' 'echo $0' | ./foo
./foo
```

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters):

> ($0) Expands to the name of the shell or shell script. This is set at
>   shell initialization. If Bash is invoked with a file of commands (see
>   [Shell Scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Scripts)), `$0` is set to the name of that file. If Bash is
>   started with the `-c` option (see [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash)), then `$0` is
>   set to the first argument after the string to be executed, if one is
>   present. Otherwise, it is set to the filename used to invoke Bash, as
>   given by argument zero.

Comment: I'll be goddamned